# Passing variable from backend to frontend laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 5 controllers and 5 models and they are all related to backend. I can easily output data in the backend but I need to that for the frontend as well. Not all of course but some of them.

For example I have controller called BooksController:

```
  public function getBooks(Request $request)
{
   $books = Books::all();

   return view('backend.books.show', compact('images'));

}
```

So this will show it in backend without any problems but what I want is for example to loop through all the books and show their images in welcome.blade.php which doesn't have controller.

And also to pass other parameters to that same view from different controllers.

Is this is possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Please read about "Back-end / Front-end" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends. Then visit Laravel views documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views

Comment: Yes I saw that but for some reason it won't show me anything all the time I get undefined variable name

Comment: So share some code please

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can't you simply render the welcome blade view file in your controller, the same way you are rendering backend.books.show there when needed?

Comment: Well if I just add welcome blade file it will return me error $image not defined

Comment: By backend and frontend you mean admin panel and front webpage?

Comment: You are asking, data which I show on admin panel should also be available on frontend's welcome.blade.php file right?

Comment: @SaravananSampathkumar yes I want to show the same data

Answer (score 0):

You are having an error because you did not declare the variable `$image`

```
public function getBooks(Request $request)
{
   $books = Books::all();

   $images = array_map(function($book) { 
      $book->image;
   }, $books);

   return view('backend.books.show', compact('images'));
}
```

Comment: No, I can show it in backend.books.show because that is in the same controller. What I want is to share `$books` with `Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome'); });` How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are potentially caught up on some terminology. In this case, it sounds like backend is referring to your admin-facing interface, and frontend is referring to your user-facing interface.

You also seem to be locked on the idea of controllers. Unless the route is verrrrrry basic, create a controller for it.

Have a controller for your welcome view, for your admin view, basically (with some exceptions) a controller per resource or view is fine.

In this case, you would have one controller for your admin book view, and a seperate controller for your welcome view. Both of which would pull the books out of the db and render them in their own way